# Checkmarx not identifying library

Tags: checkmarx

We had a library for Sanitizers, that we created for Fortify and it was working fine. But the same is not working in Checkmarx. We have that library as a dependent in our pom.xml. Does anyone have idea why is it so?

Thanks.

Comment: I think currently Checkmarx can't scan library out of the source. You can define its methods as sanitizers with the `Plugin` feature, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new CX Query or add your sanitizing methods/class to the existing query of Checkmarx